# My jquery.cookie.js report error

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my templates I include the `jquery` and `jquery.cookie.js`, but get the below error:

[image]

The below is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>cookie-login1</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/cookie/login1/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="text" name="pwd">
        <input type="submit" value="add">
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="button-add">
    </form>


</body>


<script src="/static/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'/cookie/login1/',
                type:"POST",
                data:{'username':'root', 'pwd':'123'},
                success:function(response){

                }
            })
        })
    })

</script>

</html>
```

My jquery version is `2.1.4`, and my `jquery.cookie.js` version is `1.4.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import `jQuery` befor `jquery.cookie.js`.
jquery.cookie.js needs jQuery but you compiler doesn't know it to this time because you load it before jQuery.

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The html document parse order is from top to bottom , you should import the `jquery` first:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```